# TurboGear framework python 3.7 doesnt work quickstart

Tags: python, turbogears

I have a problem with my programming environment, after many tries to use turbogears library in my project (I need the DataGrid method) I left it and try another project.

I think I make some kind of mistake because I cannot create a project with

```
gearbox quickstart name_proj
```

I  have got

```
ERROR [gearbox] Unknown command 'quickstart'
```

In the past it works, probably I destroy sth with many tries to install many versions of turbogears

Comment: my OS: Windows 10 Pro x64

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to install the `tg.devtools` package. The `quickstart` command is not part of TurboGears itself, but part of the Development Tools.